# typescript recursive include , recursive pick

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

i have a lot of interfaces types that extend some other "unknown" bit and nested types , and i want to extract recursively some properties i care . so this is what i was thinking

```
//pseudocode
type RecursiveInclude< T,  keys> = // implementation here

type A = {
  keyToKeep: string
  keyToOmit: string
  nested: {
    keyToKeep: string
    keyToOmit: string
    foo:string,
    nested2:{
       keyToKeep: string
       keyToOmit: string
    }
    
  }
  nestedOptional?: {
    keyToKeep: string
    keyToOmit: string
  }
}

// type Result = RecursiveInclude<A, 'keyToKeep' |  'foo' | 'anyotherproperty'>

type Expected = {
  keyToKeep: string
  nested: {
    keyToKeep: string
    foo:string,
    nested2:{
       keyToKeep: string
    }
  }
  nestedOptional?: {
    keyToKeep: string
  }
}
```

// any idea  or approximation is welcome, so dont be shy

https://stackoverflow.com/users/125734/titian-cernicova-dragomir

give me some inspiration, this is what he has created so far,

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBABQJYGMDWARJBnMAnJAIwFcwkA3GAHgBUAaOAaThgA8wYA7AE20TwD2sPJEYwIAPjgBeODRbsuvOAENOEOAH44ACnlsOPPgMIArGCjBa4ASW5Vk6AEoXiebBRgAbCLQaMJKQAuOQBKOBDOGEo8AG5QSFhbexopWQBvAF84ADI4dLgAbQQ4JE44NHEBADM5AF0IuWK67IB6VrgAYQFsAFsYMhQ4Ymx4AU4fOF6VSr4wAAt4MAEBLzIoPjYoFW44BaXoeBQ1OEJ4PBhegUpdhMPEVDQXFDcPSh9aBUNlNQh-L6UfAQgmEonEaQe6CooDgsPyRRKZQqVVqNDqIUcmBw+CIpE8tGa-ikmToMLhAFF2HgVJYqIwGJUIDU5BJQKyQKA7kkAIIyfJkxk0ARiGBQEK4AicADmAvEQoA8r0kGBxTjpWSorgYNwQukybDBcKYKLVZKZSA4ciIAqlSq4BKyubLdUVkEHeqLXBMhqYFruPKoGRxiovJpdfqrUKRWL7WqnXDDYrlabHWTvSB01z4C5sMQ1nzMc9Xp4PtyGAByQ3R8twAA+cHLLoENfr5d+An2eCgIJgeAg5fZWbglNglm1fL1nqrxpj7vjmo4Ov5noNcqNJtjZojTbdcbTPr9AaDnBDYeXlunG7n+4zcFAQA

the only caveat there is you need to know all the keys so you can traverse all the properties
meaning you need to provide all the keys on the type

```
'keyToKeep' |  'nested' | 'nested2' | 'nestedOptional' | 'foo' | 'anyotherproperty'
```

is closer , but the original problem i dont have access to that information --> meaning this keys

```
|  'nested' | 'nested2' | 'nestedOptional' |
```

Comment: If an object has no keys you want to keep, I assume you want it to become `{}` and not `never`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible way to proceed:

```
type OmitNever<T> = Omit<T,
  { [K in keyof T]-?: 
    Pick<T, K> extends Partial<Record<K, undefined>> ? K : never 
  }[keyof T]
>;

type RecursivePick<T extends object, K extends PropertyKey> = OmitNever<{
  [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? T[P] : (
    T[P] extends infer O ? O extends object ? RecursivePick<O, K> : never : never
  )
}> extends infer O ? { [P in keyof O]: O[P] } : never
```

You can verify it works on your type:

```
type Result = RecursivePick<A, 'keyToKeep' | 'foo' | 'anyotherproperty'>
/* type Result = {
    keyToKeep: string;
    nested: {
        keyToKeep: string;
        foo: string;
        nested2: {
            keyToKeep: string;
        };
    };
    nestedOptional?: {
        keyToKeep: string;
    } | undefined;
} */
```

The approach here is to walk through your object and keep each property if its key is in `K`.  If the key is *not* in `K`, then check if the property is an object.  If not, you want to omit the property entirely.  If so, then you want to recurse down into the property with `RecursivePick`.

Note that it's not possible to omit a property while you're iterating with a mapped type.  So instead I set the property to `never` and then run `OmitNever<T>` on the resulting object.  This has the side effect that any nested property of type `never` will be eliminated:

```
type Oops = RecursivePick<{a: never}, "a"> // {}
```

If that's a big deal we could change the definition of `RecursivePick` to preserve `never` properties by using some other sentinel,  but I doubt it.

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gtgS2AOQgNwgJwDwBUB8UAvLIsHgDQCwAUFFAN5QDaA0lAgHZQDWEIAewBmUXAF0AtAH4AXFAAKCAMY9KUVoQgAPYBE4ATAM4KAhpmAITAG2wAlCEoGZ92VhSgBXAxCFcI+-EIpdSg5TnQsKABfZj5BEXFafABuWlBIKHslD0xDBAxFFTwobV0DYwEAIwArB2B3dlK9IwVMAUhzEFZ+QhJ4JFQMHAZaemZ5Dm444VExOQmm8pDg3HGxUKgAClH6UTWSnWbjLiFImChg88WWqtqlYAvMhxy8guVVGAbCMIjMDfChjsAJS0KKaQ5LE5nR5McaTXj8GYwOawfZRf6-WhYmjpaAAWQ8wA81isIAAohCjMVrsYAKruWkHMotABq7hZxFEvSgaAECH0qRoaXA0AAgpyRnQESBcAJuhAwHJDMBMFwAOY7OKy-rAJUq9U7cLK-xySW7aWy+WKqDK1WcDVS+hagQ6vV2h3moQCARu9XUR1QI26fQAJlNO3NzqtvvtEd2ztdNv1sYDUWx9DTUqD-hgYAsAk41lkjDjUYgCpjHvj-G1ZErO0zmdxUFFovuxKsnKyL3yEEKqlF7gA5GWFUOoAAfKBDr0CcdTocmTiCYAACywYDaHVAQ-wwoyoopkHu-glmprcvL1ttBqzEGN+nDAdH1+TVfos8r-vN2dDT-NToXtGSbunGmYZoa97Brm+aFlYxZmtWMqXhWIG3hBNBNiKLa4FBnIEkSJLkpShjYK27bWO4h5aMewZ7kKOLYQAWmeUqOHAYBLiA-67IWcAQJWgrmiY+j6Jg96GDxP4mPxglxvQYACMqjj6AJaEpuaURCbsyoeEIQhSbsJjFje9raealQmW+5m7EoVnujZ4E6SAcByVKjb7tATFtoRnYkN2uS9v22BMcOfEQLugrNkxR51KeJCIexnHLoZ4VucJoniYYkklgG9BpepaqOTZun6aa6IAPQVVA2ASBIUBrlgEXGJwAhQJgHhWNAa4mA84lwAIGDGBAHGgFAtx1IYDaClhGRMbhyr4YSHakhSzKkd5FFWO4MU0XFASCtiQA)

Comment: this is pretty close, and the approach works for me, the only thing missing is:
your approach is eliminating the nestedOptional? is not keeping the { keyToKeep: string }

is there anyway we can sort this out, and i really appreciate your help 
thanks

Comment: heh, oops.  updated.  The problem was that I needed to [distribute](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#distributive-conditional-types) the operation over unions in `T[P]`, so that `{} | undefined` will be treated differently from `undefined`.

Comment: beautiful, thanks a lot ,thats exactly what i need , you  save my day,  thanks

Comment: This does not seem to work if an object has optional keys, [Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/wXkrQW) - any ideas how to resolve?

Comment: Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/WJ8xVN) work for your use cases?  I don't see any requirement that something like `Pick<{a: string}, never>` should result in `never`, so I would think that you'd end up with the `stuff` key being present with an empty object inside.  Otherwise the scope of the problem changes.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is only there to help you with compile time error checking. It is compiled to JavaScript and does not do anything for run-time. Much like the spoon in the Matrix, types and interfaces don't exist.

Creating a type to pick out properties in an object only helps you to select those objects when writing code. It does not remove them from an object in the final code.

If you don't have access to the information at compile time, you have to resort to finding properties and making sure they exist through JavaScript means. You can create type guards to help you do this while still keeping some of the typing that you are aware of.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Comment: This is a good disclaimer in general, but I'm not sure it applies to the particular question.  I presume the question is about the type system and not runtime JS objects.  Do you see something that indicates a desire to omit properties at runtime?

Comment: He mentions "the original problem is I don't have access to that information --> meaning this keys" which leads me to believe he's wanting to traverse an object without knowing the structure. This is why I believe it's outside of the TypeScript scope.

Comment: I suppose we will find out what OP thinks, but my interpretation is that this is a question about the object *types* and not their runtime values.